# Wrapping libcurl with std::streambuf for uploads?

Tags: c++, libcurl, ftp-client, streambuf

I've implemented the read half of the `std::streambuf` API (i.e., `underflow()` and `xsgetn()`) around libcurl so that an ordinary `istream` can have such a `streambuf` plugged into it and retrieve the contents from HTTP or FTP servers. It works great.

Now I'd like to implement the write half of the API (i.e., `overflow()` and `xsputn()`) for uploading files to an FTP server to do something like:

```
ostream os( my_curl_streambuf );
curl_easy_setopt( my_curl_handle, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L );
os << is->rdbuf(); // copy entire contents of istream "is" to ostream "os"
```

The problem is that libcurl uses a "pull" API via a read-callback function set via `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` whereas the last code line above is a "push" way of doing it.

Can this be made to work? I.e., wrap libcurl with the `streambuf` API for both reading *and* writing?

Comment: It can be done, but no matter how you do it, you're stuck with the fact that sockets are asynchronous, and streams are synchronous, so no matter *how* you do it, it's probably not going to work well enough to justify the work.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the "It can be done" part? I'll be the one to decide whether it's worth the work.

Comment: One possible starting point would be: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/14389/489.

Comment: That code is *only* for reading -- which my code already does (and does it better since it handles time-outs). I specifically asked about *writing*.

Comment: Hmm...I seemed to recall its having a `write` and a `writecallback` (or something on that order) that looked like they were for writing. If I mis-remembered (or misread), I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about the libcurl API but I would expect that it pulls data until all data is exhausted. Since IOStreams have a push interface which won't be married easily with a pull interface it seem you'd best implement a stream which buffers all output until it is complete and at this point have libcurl pull for the readily available buffer. You'd probably have `sync()` do nothing and instead provide a custom function, say, `send()` on your stream which is the trigger to hand over control to libcurl until it is down with its business.

The alternative approach would be to use a thread for libcurl to pull on and another thread to write to the stream and feed the bits which are written to libcurl when it pulls for data.